# "Both which" or "both of which"

Tags: prepositions, determiners, expression-choice

> "This can be done using the technique of Peters, and using the
> technique of Matthews, both which involve mathematics"

Having searched "*both which*" and "*both of which*" in Google, it appears "*both of which*" is more often used.

1. Why?
2. What does the "*of*" do?
3. If the "*of*" is necessary, why is it not necessary in the following sentence: "This can be done using the technique of Peters, which involves mathematics"?

Comment: a third alternative is "which both".  This actually sounds more natural to me in the context that you've supplied.

Comment: Perhaps you are less interested in the specific case of "both" than you are in the general rules governing the usage of indefinite pronouns (both, either, neither, several, each, etc.). If so, I refer you [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=s80DfCU_08MC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=indefinite+pronouns+prepositional+phrases&source=bl&ots=tDFQJ3v7fe&sig=eLy_GkytYaTt_RtcyGKqQSuaTNk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rfS8T4bsMeiM6QGG8NAl&ved=0CFgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=indefinite%20pronouns&f=false).

Comment: Hey, I’m not going to fight over it if you don’t think there’s consensus, but can you explain why you rolled back my edit on the MSE “unpin the accepted answer on ELU” question?

Comment: @DanBron the vote tally is 8 to 8, so there's no consensus.

Comment: @NikeDattani It was 9 to 7 last I checked, and bear in mind the rule established on ELU meta is we count the upvotes but *not* the downvotes, to prevent double counting. In that light, the difference is even starker (makes it 12 to 9 for unpin). Add to that that I personally posted both the *pro* and *contra* answers, and so am prohibited from voting on either, but would vote for unpin if I could, so there’s another implicit +1 for unpinning (13 v 9). That said, I’m willing to wait another week (again) to see if anything changes. If it doesn’t, I’m going to reinstate my edit on the MSE answer

Comment: @DanBron I see that Andrew Leach believes only upvotes should be counted, but  where was that consensus established? Furthermore, you just said you want accepted posts to be unpinned, and you wrote the initial question. That means the initial question may have had some bias in it, and likewise and decision you make on what the consensus is. Considering that SE has worked one way for 13+ years, and that SE has now decided to maintain the status quo (all sites except SO will by default, pin the accepted answer unless a site agrees otherwise), it would be a drastic change (clear consensus needed)

Comment: @NikeDattani Andrew is a mod; he’s setting the rules, not asking for consensus on it. And it makes sense for binary questions; it’s clear some keep-pin users downvoted the unpin answer, but only one unpin user downvoted the keep-pin answer. That has lead to double voting and vote dilution. As for bias in the question: I consciously and deliberately tried my best to keep the *question* neutral and put my arguments in the *answer*. As for the rest: the whole point of the vote is to make this decision. Votes will decide the outcome.

Comment: 1 mod does not set the rules. Neither do 3.

Comment: @DanBron I'm in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59286886#59286886) if you want to ping me there.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. thanks! I clicked that link and found that I'd already upvoted the two "keep pin" answers, but let me know if there's anything else I can do to help! I'm also pingable in Chat by replying to [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59286886#59286886) if you'd like to chat more in a different place.

Answer (score 7):

The "of" is optional; both constructions are grammatically correct. Note, however, that an article or pronoun is mandatory with "both of." "Both of *the* techniques" (article), "both of *their* techniques" (possessive pronoun), "both of *these* techniques" (demonstrative pronoun), and "both of *which*" (relative pronoun referring to "techniques") are all acceptable. <strike>"Both of techniques"</strike>, on the other hand, is not.

The reason "both of which" may show up on Google more times than "both which" has to do with **rhythm--*not* grammar**. English is said to flow in [iambic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter) rhythms, forming a general pattern of alternating weak and strong stresses, much like your heartbeat. The "of," in this case, creates a weak beat separating what would be two strong stresses in "both which."

The question of whether a particular syllable constitutes a strong or weak stress depends on the immediately surrounding context. A pattern that our vocal apparatus has difficulty pronouncing ("both which") will slow things down, resulting in a series of consecutive strong beats (spondaic rhythm), while reversing the pattern of stresses or introducing filler words can create something more iambic ("which both" or "both of which"). Most native speakers of English don't even think about these matters of prosody, but I know from experience that they can be annoying to students learning English. Good writers and speakers develop a sense for how they can shape meaning and emphasis by manipulating speech rhythm.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure the following excerpt from an 'Oxford University Press' book will clear all your doubts:

We can put both (*of*) before nouns and pronouns. Before a noun with a determiner (for example: *the, my, these*), *both* and *both of* are both possible.

> **Both (of) my** parents like riding.
>
> She's eaten **both (of) the** chops.

We can also use *both* without a determiner.

> She's eaten **both** chops. (=...**both of the** chops.)

Only *both of* is possible before a personal pronoun (*us, you, them*).

> **Both of them** can come tomorrow.
>
> Mary sends her love to **both of us.**

We can put *both* after object pronouns.

> I've invited **them both**.
>
> Mary sends **us both** her love.
>
> I've made **you both** something to eat.

Comment: ..and therefore, (since *which* stands for *them*), 'of' is required.

Answer (score 1):

'Of' is linked to both, not which.
In the same way you would say "Both of my brothers like sport".

Comment: But you do not *have* to say “both of my brothers”; you can just say “both my brothers”. In contrast, you *must* say “both **of** which”; leaving out the “of” there makes it no longer seem a grammatically well-formed construct, at least to me.

Comment: I fully agree with you that 'both my brothers' is acceptable (and more compact). So why is 'both which' not "grammatically well-formed" ?

Answer (score 1):

added: **If you understand English the simple answer is, OF is used when "which" is not used as a question. Otherwise you can tell by the context or content of the sentence if it implies a question such as, where were you? Otherwise it suggests a comment which is "relative" to the previous comment. Here, OF adds style, formality, poetic or professorial quality to English in both written or spoken form.**

*Which* is better, **to start a question** with **which**, the pronoun to start an *interrogative* question with multiple choices or to **make a statement** *of which* might offer a statement. {of reason or proof or opinion, for example}

Both **of **which**** are two examples of different meanings.

Here, there is no confusion, as to *which* is ***which***, or am I wrong?

Can you see the difference in structure and where "of" is necessary to distinguish easily a question from a statement or relevance or relative to a noun, now being an **adjective**?

So, in short use "**of which**", when it is **not a question**, to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for answering Tony, but with all due respect, that was not easy for me to follow!

Comment: English is not easy nor was this question. Or let me make that perfectly clear. "OF WHICH" adds clarity, but "OF" is redundant, due to the context within the sentence or the inflection in your voice using a question. IN fact MANY english words are REDUDANT to express an idea. Emphasis is only for Style. YOu might not be able to tell , but I prefer BREVITY.   My conclusion says it all, my example was over the top with double meanings. Sorry but I dare you will forget the meaning now that you understand.