# "Both of" vs. just "both" with mathematical symbols

Tags: prepositions, american-english, mathematics

In mathematical writing we use letters to denote the mathematical objects we are writing about.  I wonder how to use "both of" in the following phrase:

> Both of I and I' are irreducible ideals.

vs.

> Both I and I' are irreducible ideals.

I am writing in American English. More abstractly, should I treat mathematical symbols as nouns?

Comment: possible duplicate: [“Both which” or “both of which”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68669/both-which-or-both-of-which)

Comment: Best just to leave it off: _I and I' are irreducible ideals_.

Comment: @MattЭллен, the questions overlap to extent of both asking about *both* vs *both of*, but this question seems to allow either form (possibly with the first preferred), and the other question primarily the second form.  Ie, a combined question could ask both things, but as is they aren't duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I and I' are nouns in this sentence, your second example is the correct usage.

> Both I and I' are irreducible ideals.

To see how this works, compare with:

> Both of cat and dog are animals

vs

> Both cat and dog are animals

Comment: I agree.  I don’t recall ever having seen _both of_ used in mathematical writing.

Comment: @DanielHarbour, I disagree with Rory, but haven't downvoted, preferring to reserve judgement.  Rory, have you got a shred of evidence for what you say, other than the irrelevant cat and dog?

Comment: The cat and dog could have been any nouns - my choice was arbitrary to highlight basic sentence structure.

Comment: Rory, you have still offered no evidence to support your claim that I, I′ being nouns makes a difference. Here is my reasoning: Either of “Both I and I' are...” and “Both of I and I' are...” is acceptable, and the latter sounds better; your “rule” says the latter isn't acceptable; so your “rule” is wrong; hence your answer is wrong and should be downvoted.  (By the way, I wouldn't say either phrase, but instead something like “I and I' both are irreducible ideals” or “Ideals I and I' are both irreducible.”)

Comment: Hahahaha. You may not like it but it is still correct. Your second example also works, but your first one is not common phrasing.

Comment: Why are I and I' nouns?

Comment: Because they are items or objects. Sure, they are imaginary, but then so are ghosts - still nouns :-)