# Can I say ''Both of you and I are...'' instead of ''Both of us are...''?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct if I  say ''Both of you and I are...'' instead of ''Both of us are...''? I need help.

Comment: Delete the _of_ if you want to use _I_. If you want to keep the _of_, use _me_ instead of _I_. This is assuming you want to mean _both of us_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Both of you and I are..." says something about three people: it's the same as "The two of you and I are...", and the grammatical structure is like "both of you" + "I" or "the two of you" + "I".

If you're talking about two people, use "both you and I are...", which means "the two of us are".

Related post that gives some other rules for "both" and "both of": ["Both which" or "both of which"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68669/both-which-or-both-of-which)

user20934's answer says that "both of" is required before a personal pronoun, but this rule doesn't seem to apply when *both* is used as part of the "both...and..." construction.

Cambridge Dictionary's *[English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/both)* describes the "both...and..." construction as a "linking expression".

Comment: Calling the Oxford Comma!  :-)   (Yes, I know this isn't where it's called for, but "Both of you [two] -comma - and I..."  might clarify the meaning)